# Emulate access specifiers in C

Tags: c++, c, oop

Is it possible to emulate C++ access specifiers [public, private, protected] in C ? More generally, how does the C++ compiler ensure that private members of a class are not accessed by non-member functions ?

Comment: What would be the point? Those keywords are used to specify method behavior in an object-oriented environment.

Comment: The C++ compiler reads the code and keeps list of what has visibility where. The emulation of this in C will require some some work using macros and the precompiler and thinking about what it actually means to be private in a C program. And it will only by a rough approximation.

Comment: @Michael: Curiosity. Since its possible to implement virtual function mechanism in C using func pointers and vtables, consequently emulating polymorphism, I was wondering if its possible to emulate encapsulation.

Comment: In C++, the access specifiers are a part of the type system. You'll have to emulate that aspect of C++'s type system in C. What combination of preprocessor and linker magic you'd use in accomplishing that is up to you. Invoking opaque types here is IMHO a long stretch.

Comment: The thing with encapsulation is that it is not truly an enforcement, but only a way to discourage and make access to members more obscure to do. If someone really wants to, it will be able to violate C++ encapsulation. As what is said of Python's lack of encapsulation enforcement, "we are all grown up here". If you designed your attributes to be private, whoever used it directly must know what he/she is doing, and assume the risks.

Answer (score 6):

C++ access control is entirely a figment of the compiler's imagination: you can't access a private member only because the compiler will refuse to compile any code that tries to do so.

It's actually fairly simple to access a private member of a C++ class by tricking the compiler into thinking that a pointer to an instance of `ClassWithPrivateMember` is actually a pointer to an instance of `ClassWithPublicMember` -- i.e., by using a slightly modified header file, you can generally get access to things you shouldn't. Not that anyone ever does anything like that...

The best way to do access control in C is by passing around pointers to an opaque type: `struct` objects the definition of which is not available to client code. If you provide a `foo* create_foo()` method and a series of methods that operate on `foo*`, hiding the actual definition of `foo` from the client, then you'll have achieved a similar effect.

```
// File "foo_private.h"
struct foo {
    int private1;
    char private2;
};

// File "foo.h"
typedef struct foo foo;
foo * create_foo(int x, char y);
int mangle_foo(foo *);

// file "foo.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo_private.h"

foo * create_foo(int x, char y) {
    foo * f = (foo *) calloc(1, sizeof(foo));
    f->private1 = x;
    f->private2 = y;
}    

int mangle_foo(foo *f) {
    return f->private1 + f->private2;
}
```

Now, you distribute `foo.c` compiled into a library, along with `foo.h`. The functions declared in `foo.h` form the public interface of a type, but the internal structure of that type is opaque; in effect, the clients who call `create_foo()` can't access the private members of the `foo` object.

Our friend the `FILE*` is a similar sort of thing, except that the type `FILE` isn't usually truly opaque. It's just that most people (wisely) don't go poking through its innards. There, access control is enforced merely by obscurity.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you give an example for "a series of methods that operate on void*, hiding the implementation from the client, then you'll have achieved a similar effect."

Comment: See, this is exactly what opaque types are for, since a void * gives no semantic clues as to what's going on: typedef struct thing thing_t; and you have a type which says "no user-serviceable parts inside" while still providing information about what the type is supposed to do.

Comment: `void*` throws away type safety. There are better ways to do this.

Comment: @blueshift -- modified my example to use opaque types.

Comment: Seems a bit confused still, `typedef struct f foo;` and `struct foo;` (unused?), and create_foo still returns void. Did you test this..?

Comment: @blueshift Well... no. But I did now.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise strongly against using void* pointers as suggested in another answer *(since fixed)*, that throws away all type-safety. You can instead forward-declare `struct foo;` in a header without specifying the contents, then you can pass those structs and pointers to them in and out of interface functions declared in a header. The struct implementation is hidden inside that unit's .c file.

If you want to keep the option of changing between a struct and other types e.g. int, you can use `typedef` in your header to wrap the type for the interface.

Other techniques you can use include declaring functions inside that .c file `static` so that they cannot be linked from other sources, even if those other sources declare the function.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve the goal, followings are mine:

The example includes a class "struct test_t" and a class function "test_create" and a member function "print"

test.h:

```
struct test_t {
    // Member functions
    void (*print)(struct test_t *thiz);

    // Private attributes
    char priv[0];
};


// Class functions
struct test_t *test_create(int number);
```

test.c:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// priv attr
struct test_priv_t {
    int number;
};


// member functions
static void print(struct test_t *thiz)
{
    struct test_priv_t *priv = (struct test_priv_t*)thiz->priv;
    printf("number = %d\n", priv->number);
}


// Class functions
struct test_t *test_create(int number)
{
    struct test_t *test = (struct test_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct test_t) + sizeof(struct test_priv_t));

    // setup member function
    test->print = print;

    // initialize some priv attr
    struct test_priv_t *priv = (struct test_priv_t*)test->priv;
    priv->number = number;

    return test;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    struct test_t *test = test_create(10);
    test->print(test);
}
```